# How to Insert ListItemCollection in to SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

How to Insert ListItemCollection in to SharePoint List using CSOM

Answer (score 2):

You have to insert each item separately for example like this:

```
ListItemCollection items = null; // get the items somehow

// List columns that you want to copy from source item to new item
var columns = new[] { "Title", "SomeOtherColumn", "Created", "Author" };
foreach (ListItem item in items)
{
    ListItem newItem = list.AddItem(new ListItemCreationInformation());
    foreach (string columnName in columns)
    {
        newItem[columnName] = item[columnName];
    }
    newItem.Update();
}

ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```